# "behave like us" vs "behave like we (do)"

Tags: pronouns

Consider a sentence:

> They behave like us

Why do we use "us" here? Should it be subjective pronoun "we" as it is a subject of implied verb "do", i.e.

> They behave like we (do)

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got it backwards.  First, you look at what people actually say, **then** you come up with an analysis.  If people actually said **they behave like we*, then the ellipsis analysis would be reasonable.  But since we don't say that, the ellipsis analysis must be wrong.

Instead, *like* must be introducing a noun phrase, not a verb phrase, and so the accusative *us* is the natural choice.  This is perfectly standard and has been for hundreds of years.  Of course, it can introduce a verb phrase as well:

> 1. They behave like us.  *(standard, introducing noun phrase)*
>
> 2. They behave like we do.  *(standard, introducing verb phrase)*

Historically, some prescriptivists have taught people that option 1 is incorrect, despite the fact that it's standard English.  But even those who reject option 1 above would not omit *do*:

> 3. *They behave like we.  *(non-standard omission of do)*

So if you want to say *we*, make sure you say *do* as well.

---

*In this answer, * marks a sentence that is not standard English.*

Comment: Brava! That second sentence should be inscribed on our landing page, like *gnōthi seauton* in the forecourt at Delphi.